# Why does mocked axios get method return undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

I've written a fairly simple async method that retrieves results over HTTP:

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URI = "http://api.tvmaze.com";

export const getSearchShows = async (search: string) => {
  const uri = `${BASE_URI}/search/shows?q=${encodeURIComponent(search)}`;
  const response = await axios.get(uri);

  return response.data;
};
```

I want to unit-test it. So I write the following Jest test, which intends to mocks axios and return fake results, which I can then assert on:

```
import axios from "axios";

import fakeSearchShowsResponse from "../data/search-shows--q=test.json";

import { getSearchShows } from "./TvShows.http";

jest.mock("axios");

describe("TvShows.http", () => {
  describe("getSearchShows", () => {
    it("retrieves shows over http and correctly deserializes them", async () => {

      const mockAxiosGet = jest.spyOn(axios, "get");

      mockAxiosGet.mockImplementation(async () => fakeSearchShowsResponse);

      const shows = await getSearchShows("test");

      console.log(mockAxiosGet.mock.calls);

      expect(shows[0].id).toEqual(139);

    });
  });
});
```

I expected that, due to calling `jest.mock("axios")`, the axios get method would have been replaced with a mocked Jest method.

Furthermore, I expected that due to calling `mockAxiosGet.mockImplementation` and passing it a function, a call to the axios get method would actually call my mock function, allowing me to substitute test data for real data.

What actually happens is that the call to axios get returns `undefined`, causing my test assertion to fail.

And yet, oddly enough, the Jest spy still registers that the method was called – the console.log outputs a single call.

So why is this supposedly mocked method returning `undefined` when I explicitly provided a mock implementation that returns a value?

Or do I misunderstand how mockImplementation is meant to be used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So after some experimentation, it would appear that the `jest.mock("axios")` call was interfering with the `jest.spyOn(axios, "get");` call.

After removing the jest.mock call, it now returns my mocked value from the jest.spyOn call.

I think this might be because the jest.mock call was hoisted, whereas the jest.spyOn call wasn't. So the module under test was going off the hoisted mock rather than the un-hoisted one.

Answer (score 2):

`jest.mock('axios')` would mock the entire module, replacing everything with a stub. So it doesn't necessarily have relation with the fact that `jest.mock()` is hoisted, it is only to make sure dependency is mocked before import. It's just the stub returning `undefined`.

Meanwhile, you could

```js
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

console.log(axios); // mocked

describe('suite', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue('{"test": "test"}');
    // --------------------------^
    // you class would get this when calling axios.get()

    // you could also do some assertion with the mock function
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCallWith('http://some-url');
  });
});
```